# What does an NServiceBus endpoint do when Stop() is called while processing a message

Tags: nservicebus

We are moving from a home grown bus to NServiceBus and I am migrating our current endpoints. Currently if an endpoint gets a stop request it will:

1. Stop receiving messages from the queue
2. Complete processing of any messages currently in the pipeline
3. Stop/Shutdown

What does an NServiceBus endpoint do when IEndpointInstance.Stop() is called?  Does it complete handling the current messages normally?  Does it abort or cancel them?  I can't find any documentation that outlines the steps followed when Stop is called, does any exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Marbach already provided an answer on our Google Groups
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/particularsoftware/YjveqZYOs6c/gL1VIgxPAwAJ

It's basically the same as what you'd expect, but differs from transport and depends on transaction mode.

- It will stop receiving messages from the queue
- Finish handling messages currently in the pipeline (some transports do that
  indefinitely like RabbitMQ or have a timeout of 30 seconds i.ex. MSMQ)
- Stop/shutdown

Comment: Thanks Dennis!  I did see Daniel's answer on the google group as well.